# Does Ubuntu 18.04 allow snap packages to be reviewed / rated, and if so, where do I see that information?

Tags: 18.04, software-center, snap

For years, I've relied on the ratings and reviews in the Software Center to guide some of my application choices, when there are multiple applications that are available for a given need. Independent reviews from users can be useful to nudge me away from poorly working applications and towards ones that are superior. (I'm fully aware that some people may find those reviews and/or ratings not useful to them, but they are useful to *me*.)

I have found that I can neither view nor submit ratings or reviews for snap applications that are accessible in the Software Center of Ubuntu 18.04. I can find no answers to this on various snap web pages or in the Software Center itself as to why this is. Is it possible to publish ratings and reviews of these snap apps, and if so, where add my own ratings and reviews and view those submitted by other users?

Answer (score 2):

The ability to add ratings and reviews to snaps in "Ubuntu Software" was only recently enabled.

The version of Ubuntu Software from the deb repositories, shipped in 18.04 doesn't yet have this feature enabled. However, there is a [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/snap-store) snap which does have this capability. It's essentially a newer build of Ubuntu Software, which only allows installing snaps.